# Interpreting times shown on an strace for open system calls

Tags: linux, io, system-calls, strace

We are having latency issue with a vendor application. I ran an `strace -Tttt` on the process and got this:

```
[...]
1470166748.946144 open("/opt/app/shdbrth/X       ", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) <0.000016>
1470166800.850979 open("/opt/app/shdbrth/X38347", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 10 <0.000070>
1470166800.851139 fstat(10, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0660, st_size=0, ...}) = 0 <0.000006>
[...]
```

According to the [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace), the `-ttt` prefixes each line with the time the syscall was made. The `-T` option appends the time the call took to process in between `<` and `>` brackets. However, this doesn't seem to add up in the above example.

For instance, the 2nd line started at 1,470,166,800 epoch seconds and 850,979 microsecs. According to the appended timer, it took 70 microsecs to process. However, the next line starts at the same epoch seconds and 851,139 microsecs---a difference of 90 microsecs.

I was going to write that off as just overhead but perhaps there's a more accurate explanation.

Comment: Sorry if i am being too obvious: It looks like is trying to find that file or a file that this file depends on: /opt/app/shdbrth/X... Is this file at the folder, if it is, it probably depends on something else...

Comment: The program is probably doing more than just system calls, if that's what you're wondering about. These calls could come from deep within a library doing all sorts of other things that takes time inbetween them.

Comment: @LucianoAndressMartini No need to apologize for something that seems obvious. Usually, that's the right answer :-). But what I don't understand is whether or not the IO search for the file should be included in the appended time (70 microsecs).

Comment: @Kusalananda Hm, okay.. that makes sense. User space stuff. Should have thought of that.

Comment: Also, `strace` may not show certain calls (that `ltrace` might) due to things like `gettimeofday` that have been optimized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The time at the beginning of the line is the time when the kernel started processing that system call. The duration at the end of the line is the interval between the time when the kernel started processing that system call and the time when the kernel replied to the system call.

The time at the beginning of the next line is the time when the kernel started processing that next system call. Between the reply to one system call and the entry into the next system call, two kinds of things happened: the process ran user code, and potentially other processes were scheduled on the same processor.

In your example, the first `open` call took 16µs, and the next call was issued about 12s later. During those twelve seconds, the process ran user code, and was probably preempted many times to run other processes. Between the second `open` call and the subsequent `fstat`, about 90µs elapsed; given how small this is, it suggests that the process ran only a small amount of user code and wasn't preempted.

Comment: This is a great explanation. Not sure where the downvote comes from. Thanks @Gilles.

Comment: On a side note: to decode UNIX timestamps: `perl -E 'say scalar localtime $ARGV[0]' 1470166800`.

Comment: @SatoKatsura Or, on Linux: `date -d @1470166800`